# Ajax call fail when parameter contain html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '/PostComment/AddComment',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: { "PostId": PostId, "CommentText": CommentText },
      success: function (data){
           alert('Ok');
      }
 });
```

The problem is that when the CommentText variable contain any html tag the ajax call fail. I know this is a strange problem, but that is what happen.

Comment: Show us, what is in `'/PostComment/AddComment'`, and what is in CommentText. Maybe you want to perform a database operation, and your data is not escaped / sanitazed.

Comment: What is the error code/message you get

Comment: The error is that the ajax is not calling any function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending encoded values to the server side:

```
commentText = encodeURIComponent(commentText);
```

On the server side, if you are using Java, then you can do:

```
String commentStr = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("commentText"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: the code on the server side String commentStr = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("commentText"), "UTF-8");

not work.
I am using asp.net mvc on the server side.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but I using asp.net, so on the sever side I should use
CommentText = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(CommentText);

Answer (score 2):

In javascript :

```
JSON.stringify(CommentText));
```

[See : 4 Things You Must Do When Putting HTML in JSON](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't solve the problem